# mitmproxy: follow 3xx redirect without letting the client know?

Tags: mitmproxy

What's the idiomatic way to handle `3XX` responses in an addon without letting the client know?

Say a client issues a request to `example.com`. We pass the request to the server and receive a `301`, `Location: https://www.example.com`. We don't want the client to see this, so we issue a new request to this new location while the client is waiting. Only when we receive a `200` response do we want to send the response back to the client.

The first thing that comes to mind is the `responseheaders(flow)` hook. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to queue a new flow to be run after the present flow completes   without resetting the client connection.

The `request` hook has the possibility to construct a `flow.response` and the handler will never send anything to the server. But none of the response hooks have a similar option.

Even if we interrupt the current flow and use the `ClientPlayback` to send a new request, we still have to eventually return to the current flow as it doesn't know anything about the `ClientPlayback`. If we kill it, interrupted or not, the connection to the client will be closed.

A few suggestions to similar questions all focus on modifying the client request in the `request` hook before it is sent; but what if we can't predict where the `301` will send us, or even if there will be several redirects before we get to content?

Curious how to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking this is something mitmproxy does not have a great answer to at the moment.
One approach that comes to mind is to use a library like [httpx](https://www.python-httpx.org/) in an `async def request` hook to populate `flow.response`, but that's quite a bit of manual setup.